# Minecraft - New Router stops LAN discovery

Tags: networking, router, troubleshooting, gaming, minecraft

Originally posted on [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/381709/minecraft-new-router-stops-lan-discovery) where it was suggested I post here

I have several Windows machines with Java Minecraft. All the machines are using the same version of Minecraft and we are logging in with different accounts on each machine. In my previous configuration, they were all able to see each other and discover any games Open to LAN. I'm therefore pretty confident that all firewall rules are properly setup.

I just upgraded to the Verizon G3100 router. All of a sudden, the computers no longer can see any Open to LAN games. Interestingly, they can still connect if I type IP:Port for a direct connection. We have tried using no mods - still no discovery of LAN games. Also tried turning off firewalls (although as stated before with the old router the firewalls were not a problem). All computers have their network configured as "private", and of course are all on the same subnet.

Since Minecraft worked fine on the previous router, I feel that the problem must be with the router as opposed to individual computer configurations. However, I can't for the life of me figure out what setting on the router could be blocking this.  Verizon is, of course, unable to help.

Any suggestions on how to tackle this?

Comment: Computer name doesn’t work, but IP address does? Sounds like a DNS problem.  Had you manually set the name of the computer on the last router (i.e. “if you see this MAC address, then call it by this name...”?

Comment: Are your devices wired, wireless, or a mix? Can two wired devices discover each other's shared LAN games?

Comment: @jg7 - discovery doesn't work.  EAch game that is "Open to LAN" is supposed to broadcast its existence.  The broadcast is not being sent or received.

Comment: @spiff - I thought it might have been a WiFi issue so I wired them all.  Still can't discover shared LAN games.

Comment: @CarlosN It looks like Minecraft uses UDP multicast to announce local game servers. I am unfamiliar with your particular router, but check to see if multicast is allowed. This would be a cause for not seeing games listed, but still being able to connect directly. Direct connection shows the connectivity is not the issue, advertisement is. Edit: check page 137 of your routers manual here- https://www.verizon.com/supportresources/content/dam/verizon/support/consumer/documents/internet/fios-router-user-guide.pdf

Comment: @jg7 - something to do with UDP makes sense.  That page of the router pointed me to the option to turn on/off IGMP.  I tried that to no avail (to be honest I'm not even sure exactly what IGMP does).

Comment: @CarlosN So you turned it on and applied the settings? Waited a minute and then started up a game on one machine and looked for the announcement on the other. But no luck? What happens if you set IGMP on, and reboot the router after application? If these steps don’t work, then you may need to Wireshark it and see if the server is being allowed to announce itself or not. If you see the IGMP packets from the client then you know the issue falls somewhere else. Try searching “IGMP Minecraft wireshark” on Google to get you going further down that road.